# Weird IOException with File.Copy: Non-existing file allegedly in use by another process

Tags: c#, exception

This is driving me nuts.

I retrieve a bunch of emails from a mailbox and save them as files in a folder.
There is currently just one mail in the mailbox (this specific mail is not the problem, tried others as well).
After retrieval I concatenate the subject of the mail with a unique GUID-string, save it as a file and create another copy of this file in a different folder.
This repeatedly gives me an IOException saying that the DESTINATION FILE could not be accessed (since it's allegedly being used by another process).
The destination file doesn't exist at this point so it cannot be in use.

Hope anyone can help or maybe give a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kevin

*EDIT* (more info)

```
        private static void _backupMailFile(string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
        {
            log.Info(String.Format("Archiving mail file '{0}' to '{1}'", sourceFile, destinationFile));

            try
            {
                File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Error while archiving mail: " + sourceFile, ex);
            }
        }
```

sourceFile = "D:\Development\POP3toSCSM\POP3toSCSM\bin\Debug\TempMails\AW_ Outlook Web App Light-47459c48-8c8c-4c51-be63-e6e2ddcc54d3.eml"

destinationFile = "C:\MailIn\Archive\AW_ Outlook Web App Light-47459c48-8c8c-4c51-be63-e6e2ddcc54d3.eml"

The folder "C:\MailIn\Archive" is empty at this point.

Permissions are valid.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @jarod, have you checked that you have sufficient permissions? Just a note.

Comment: Can you post your code, so we can see what you are actually doing?

Comment: Could you show your code that is saving the file?

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: Post your code so we can see. Are you sure that you are not creating the file first (and thereby opening it), and then when saving, you have a lock on this file yourself?

Comment: Use Stream.Close() or show your code

Comment: We need code of creating source file!

Comment: The source file is created by a 3rd party component (Chilkat).

Comment: Are you creating the file anywhere else in code? Can you please post your exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

It's either the Chilkat component (doubt that) or my wrapper class around its 'LoadEml'-method. As soon as I add System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250) after the last mail was retrieved from the mailbox, everything works just fine.
But wouldn't you agree that there's nothing wrong with the destination path as opposed to what the exception message reads?

*EDIT*
Guess I was wrong :-(

Here comes the stack trace:

StackTrace = "   bei System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   bei System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)\r\n   bei System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)\r\n   ...